# LibGDX : HTML5 not finding shaders

Tags: gwt, libgdx

I have written a LibGDX 3D project which works perfectly on Android, iOS and Desktop however when I run it in the browser, it cant find the shader files.  It can find all other files.  If I copy the shader files in to 2 strings instead it works fine also.

I load shaders like this

```
vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("vertex.glsl").readString();
fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("fragment.glsl").readString();
shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader,fragmentShader);
```

I have restarted the GWT server, cleaned, recompiled etc!

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?